# Laravel alternate routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

This doesn't seem to be working, but I wonder if something similar is possible. I want to use the same controller functions for the user view and admin view, the difference being the url and the the passed variable for the admin view.

The regular pages are made and working, but I'm trying to add the admin view. I wrote out routes as below and added `$organization_id=false` as parameter on all necessary AccountController functions. Is there a simple way I can get all these working?

```
Route::controller('/admin/organizations/{organization_id}', 'AccountController'); //works but not ideal

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function(){
    Route::controller('account',        'AccountController');   
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth_admin'), function(){
    Route::controller('/','Admin\HomeController');
    Route::controller('/organizations/{organization_id}', 'AccountController'); //doesn't work
});

Accounts controller:
public function getActiveUsers($organization_id = false)
{ ... }
```

The `Admin\HomeController` route does work

Comment: Does it throw an error or what happens? Always use the deepest route first, in this case, try swapping those two routes so that '/organizations/{organization_id}' comes before '/'

Comment: I swapped the two and it worked. I didn't realize that bc the routes file I was working from was not written that way but was still working